# Persistent CSS problem on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

For several days now, I have seen the following rendering problem on questions:

[image]

This problem seems to be on and off.  I am on a Safari browser, using a MacBook Air, and I don't seem to see this on my Android phone, which uses a mobile Chrome browser.

I actually posted this a few days ago, but then deleted when reloading the page seemed to make it go away.  Yet, it is happening again.

Comment: I wonder if the underlying problem is the same as that of all the other layout bugs that have been reported in the meantime, albeit mostly around comments, not posts.

Comment: @BoltClock That would make sense if, for example, the devs at SO recently did a big refactor which introduced some collective CSS bugs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed in the next build, see [Short answers are floating right in Safari 10.1.2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307477/short-answers-are-floating-right-in-safari-10-1-2/307499#307499) on MSE.

Comment: Hi Alf, thank you for explaining the cause of this +1.